# Upstart creates two processes instead of one

Tags: upstart, services

I'm trying to create a simple echo-service using ubuntu upstart.

For some reason upstart behaves really strange. When it starts the echo server first time everything is ok, but when it starts it second, third, etc time it creates two processes.

It's not fork and it's not daemon.

Please have a look at an example below. I have read almost all upstart documentation and don't understand what it means. I would appreciate for any help.

```
root@z-server:~# cat /etc/init/echoservice.conf
exec ncat -l 7 -k -e "/bin/cat"
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# start echoservice
echoservice start/running, process 1383
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i ncat
root      1383  0.0  0.0  17348  1328 ?        Ss   22:11   0:00 ncat -l 7 -k -e /bin/cat
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# stop echoservice
echoservice stop/waiting
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i ncat
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# start echoservice
echoservice start/running, process 1401
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i ncat
root      1401  0.0  0.0   4440   624 ?        Ss   22:12   0:00 /bin/sh -e -c ncat -l 7 -k -e "/bin/cat" /bin/sh
root      1402  0.0  0.0  17348  1324 ?        S    22:12   0:00 ncat -l 7 -k -e /bin/cat
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# stop echoservice
echoservice stop/waiting
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i ncat
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# start echoservice
echoservice start/running, process 1411
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i ncat
root      1411  0.0  0.0   4440   628 ?        Ss   22:12   0:00 /bin/sh -e -c ncat -l 7 -k -e "/bin/cat" /bin/sh
root      1412  0.0  0.0  17348  1324 ?        S    22:12   0:00 ncat -l 7 -k -e /bin/cat
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# kill -9 1411
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i ncat
root      1412  0.0  0.0  17348  1324 ?        S    22:12   0:00 ncat -l 7 -k -e /bin/cat
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# initctl status echoservice
echoservice stop/waiting
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# start echoservice
echoservice start/running, process 1421
root@z-server:~#
root@z-server:~# ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i ncat
root      1412  0.0  0.0  17348  1324 ?        S    22:12   0:00 ncat -l 7 -k -e /bin/cat
root@z-server:~#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dropping the quotes around `/bin/cat`. So do:

```
exec ncat -l 7 -k -e /bin/cat
```

The reason I say this is that the documentation says:

> Any special characters, e.g. quotes or `$' specified  will  result in the entire command being passed to a shell for expansion.

In this case there's no need to call the command via the shell, so let's make it simpler so that you don't use the shell.

If you do want to use the shell, then you might explicitly use a `script`...`end script` stanza and explicitly use a shell `exec` command in there instead.

I'm not sure why you're getting your original behaviour, but I think you may be able to fix it by avoiding use of a shell in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.
So do you mean that there is a difference between exec stanza and script stanza? I thought the difference is just one line vs multiline.

Comment: Can you please explain why I need exec command inside script stanza? Is there a difference between this exec shell command and exec stanza? I see examples with exec inside script section in man 5 init, but they don't explain why I would need it.

Comment: The documentation says that the `exec` upstart stanza uses `sh` only if it contains separate characters, whereas a `script` stanza always uses `sh`. The `exec` inside a `script` stanza is a separate shell command which replaces the shell instead of starting a new process by forking. See the `exec` manpage for details.